# Android Layout taking 40-50 secs to save and rebuild

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile, helios

Layout taking 40-50 secs to save and rebuild on Helios.Every time I save the layout/s it takes quite a while to save. This is because it redraws and Rebuilds all the Resources. Apperently this issue is on windows machine only.
I have already tried the following-

Remove Build Automatically
SDK Path same as work space
Change .png to .PNG  (This worked for some people but not me).

Any solution will be much appriciated.

Gracias~

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do use ADT 12. If I unchecked the automatic rebuild it brings to your solution but It takes as much time to compile and I'm back to the square one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ADT 12? If so, you can turn off the post compiler during saves such that it is deferred until export/deploy.

More details:
http://tools.android.com/recent/finercontroloveradtbuildprocess

We're doing a lot more work in this area (such as incremental resource compilation) which will hopefully be ready for ADT 13.